# How can I configure Jenkins pull request builder to run tests on Github dependabot PRs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dependabot

Our Github project repository is configured to receive security PRs from dependabot, and we get them periodically.

We are using Jenkins with Build Triggers so that when a user comments /test in a PR comment, it triggers a test.

However, on dependabot PRs, that ends up doing nothing.

I added "dependabot" to the jenkins whitelist, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Using Jenkins 2.249.1

Comment: which dependabot version are you using? (are you using github native one?)

Comment: Yes, the github native version

Comment: Then, dependabot would control the security patch updates anymore (they made the security alerts into the repo setting).

Comment: I guess the question is more about the Jenkins build trigger and how I can whitelist dependabot.  I must be missing something because whitelisting it isn't working.

Comment: sorry, I was mis-interpreting your question, I actually does not have done anything related Jenkins PR trigger with dependabot